# how can I toggle a class based on a inline style change triggerd by a click and drag by the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The class `moz-grab` changes to `moz-grabbing` when user click and drags cursor, how can I target that class and use it to change another class?

```
//if
<div class="rsOverflow" style="cursor: -moz-grabbing;">

//then do this 
toggle collapse_inner_on to collapse_inner_off
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Can you post your current script, maybe a fiddle and tell us what is not working?

Comment: What's wrong with regular JS?

Comment: dont mind javascript its perfectly fine, how do I make a fiddle of something that depends on several javascript plugins?

Comment: Please change your question title to a more descriptive one.

Comment: Thanks @cem just did that sorry question was quite vauge

Comment: This is still a confusing question even after the change. Are you saying that the inline style is already changing during click-and-drag and that you want to change the class at the same time? What is changing the inline style?

Comment: @Jeff yes the inline style changes from -moz-grab to -moz-grabbing when the user drags the div